# Mysql, displaying two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about SQL.

I have two tables.

```
Buy and Sell
```

In these tables are somewhat the same data.

ID, quantity, sum, timestamp

How do i print both tables, ordered by the timestamp. 
So it looks like this

```
Buy  | 1 | 5  | 100 | 14:14:14 |
Buy  | 2 | 22 | 50  | 14:14:20 |
Sell | 1 | 1  | 20  | 14:15:01 |
```

And so on.. I just have to be ordered by the timestamp

Comment: UNION, JOIN, ORDER BY ?? What you wanna do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no apparent research effort.

Comment: I haven't tried that much. Join, and OUTER join. I Had a hard time tracking it on the web, therefore i came here.

Comment: @Strawberry, I guess your right. I did though search for it on google, but without much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT 'Buy' as [Type], b.* FROM BUY as b
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Sell' as [Type], s.* FROM SELL as s
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
SELECT ID, Quantity, Sum, TimeStamp
FROM Buy
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Quantity, Sum, TimeStamp
FROM Sell
ORDER BY TimeStamp
```